# Failure reading data from I2C bus. Flow sensor Arduino project

Tags: matlab, arduino, sensors, i2c

I'm trying to read data from a flow sensor in the context of an Arduino project that aims to function as a breath sampler.

```
%% BREATH SAMPLER
%
% Start connection with Arduino board:
clear all
clc
a= arduino();
s=serial("COM4");

%%
% If more than one Arduino is connected to your PC, you have to specify the % board type you will be comunicating with:
%
% |a=arduino("com3","uno")|
%% Define variables
valvePin = 'D10';
pumpPin = 'D11';
buttonPin = 'D9';
flow0 = single(0);

%% Start connections I2c bus
addr = scanI2CBus (a, 0); %address bus sensor= device(a,'I2CAddress', char(addr)); %% Configure Arduino Pin
configurePin(a,valvePin,'DigitalOutput')
configurePin(a,pumpPin,'DigitalOutput')
configurePin(a,buttonPin,'DigitalInput')

%% Start data acquisition:
figure
h = animatedline;
ax = gca;
ax.YGrid = 'on';
stop = false;
startTime = datetime('now');

while ~stop

%Read current sensor value
readSensor = read(sensor, 3, 'uint8'); MSB= readSensor(1);
LSB= readSensor(2);

%Calculate flow from sensor values flow1=((MSB*256+LSB)-32000)/140;
diff = flow1-flow0;
flow0=flow1;

%Get current time
t = datetime('now') - startTime;
if (flow1>0) && (diff< -5)
        writeDigitalPin(a, valvePin,1);
        writeDigitalPin(a,pumpPin, 1);
else
        writeDigitalPin(a,valvePin,0);
        writeDigitalPin(a,pumpPin,0);
end

    %Add points to animation
    addpoints(h,datenum(t),flow1)

% Update axes
ax.XLim = datenum([t-seconds(15) t]); datetick('x','keeplimits')
drawnow

%Check Stop condition
stop= readDigitalPin(a,buttonPin);
end

%% Save results to a file
[timeLogs,flow] = getpoints(h);
timeSecs = (timeLogs-timeLogs(1))*24*3600;
T = table(timeSecs',flow','VariableNames',{'Time_sec','Flow'});
prompt = 'Please enter the file name: ';
fileName = input(prompt,'s');
fileName1=[fileName,'.xlsx'];

% Write table to file
writetable(T,fileName1)
% Print confirmation to command line
fprintf('Results table with %g flow measurements saved to file %s\n',...
    length(timeSecs),fileName1)
```

The idea is to be able to collect a sample from breath, activating a pump that collects air from the expiration phase.

During the sample obtention the aim is to be able to visualize all the data in an animated graph.

Apparently the connection with Arduino and with the flow sensor by I2C bus is correct,  but there’s a problem with the function that reads data from I2C bus. The output value of the sensor is constant, and the experiment can’t be performed properly.

Since I am a student with no previous experience controlling Arduino through matlab nor with I2C bus communication, I would be very grateful for any suggestions or help you can provide to solve this problem :)